# Find asymptotics for solution $x$ of $(x+1)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-x^{\frac{n+1}{n}}=5$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

It is easy to see that for any $n\geq 1$, the equation
$(x+1)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-x^{\frac{n+1}{n}}=5$ has a unique positive
solution ; call it $x_n$.

Is there a simple asymptotic formula for $x_n$ ? I tried unsuccessfully
  to find one, and computed that

$$
 \lfloor x_3 \rfloor=53, \
  \lfloor x_4 \rfloor=256, \
   \lfloor x_5 \rfloor=1256, \
   \lfloor x_6 \rfloor=6195, \
   \lfloor x_7 \rfloor=30678, \
   \lfloor x_8 \rfloor=152243, \ 
 $$

It seems that the sequence $(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n})$ is increasing
and converges to $5$.

Comment: How good an asymptotic do you want? Does $y_n < x_n < y_n+1$ suffice?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, the most usual asymptotic is something like $y_n=n^{\alpha}({\sf log}(n))^{\beta}$ with ${\lim}_{n} \frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$. I’m expecting something like that. Not quite sure I understood your question.

Comment: $$x_n \approx \frac{5^n}{e},$$ with some work, one can make the $\approx$ more precise.

Comment: $$
x_n  \sim \frac{{5^n }}{{\rm e}}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{5}{{24n^2 }} + \frac{5}{{48n^3 }} - \frac{{337}}{{5760n^4 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, we have

$$5 = (x_n+1)^{(n+1)/n} - x_n^{(n+1)/n} = \frac{n+1}{n}(x_n + \xi_n)^{1/n}\cdot 1$$

for some $\xi_n \in (0,1)$. That yields

$$x_n + \xi_n = \frac{5^n}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n} = \frac{5^n}{e}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2n} + O\left(n^{-2}\right)\right).$$